# PHP MongoDB Driver for LAMPP - Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: php, mongodb, ubuntu, composer-php, lampp

I'm trying to get MongoDB working with LAMPP here.
EDIT : Question was closed citing another post PHP Phar issue. This isn't about that.

**Timeline of Events:**

1. Installed LAMPP (PHP 8.2.4)
2. Installed MongoDB driver using `sudo /opt/lampp/bin/pecl install mongodb`.
3. Edited the **php.ini** of LAMPP which is in `/opt/lampp/etc/php.ini`- added `;extension=mongodb.so`. I don't know to which PHP this got installed, as later when I check the installed modules of LAMPP's PHP using  `/opt/lampp/bin/php-8.2.4 -m | grep mongodb`, mongodb was not listed in the modules.
4. Installed composer not with LAMPP's PHP but the system PHP - I don't remember the command.
5. Tried `composer require mongodb/mongodb` inide my project folder `/opt/lampp/htdocs/EMS` - command composer not found.
6. Removed composer using PURGE, and installed composer again with the command: `curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | sudo /opt/lampp/bin/php-8.2.4 -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer`

> viswesh@viswesh-ubuntu:/opt/lampp/htdocs/EMS$ curl -sS
> https://getcomposer.org/installer | sudo /opt/lampp/bin/php-8.2.4 --
> --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer All settings correct for using Composer Downloading...
>
> Composer (version 2.5.8) successfully installed to:
> /usr/local/bin/composer Use it: php /usr/local/bin/composer

7. Now trying to install mongdb using composer: `/usr/local/bin/composer require mongodb/mongodb`

> PHP's phar extension is missing. Composer requires it to run. Enable
> the extension or recompile php without --disable-phar then try again.

8. Then thought maybe it is referring to the global PHP again. Hence tried: `sudo /opt/lampp/bin/php-8.2.4 /opt/lampp/bin/pecl install mongodb` , and I'm getting this script on the console.. (image attached)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUQAT.png)